# How to combine two files into one with columns for each file's data?

Tags: shell-script

I have two files:

file1 contains:

```
1
2
3
4
```

file2 contains:

```
John
Sam
George
Ken
```

I want to combine these files to create one file(file3)

```
1, John
2, Sam
3, George
4, Ken
```

My thought was to use nested loops and add the comma for each line,

```
for x in file1
do
echo "$x" >> file3
for y in file2
echo ",$y" >> file3
done
done
```

Is there a command I need to use? How do I get it to x and y to appear on one line for each entry in both files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [paste](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/paste.html):

```
$ :|paste -d',' file1 - | paste -d' ' - file2
1, John
2, Sam
3, George
4, Ken
```

or:

```
$ :|paste -d', ' file1 - file2
```

where the `-d', '` argument specifies to use a comma and space as a delimiter between the contents of each file.

Comment: what about without the space? something like:
`$ :|paste -d',' file1 - | paste - file2`
1, John
2, Sam
3, George
4, Ken

Comment: you will get tab character instead of space, `paste` default delimiter is tab.

Comment: I also I thought this might work too?
`paste -d file1 file2 >> file3`\
1,John
2,Sam
3,George
4,Ken

Comment: No, it didn't. You can read the paste command manual I gave in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Another `paste` solution

```
paste -d ', ' file1 /dev/null file2
1, John
2, Sam
3, George
4, Ken
```

Comment: Or maybe shorter `:|paste -d', ' file1 - file2`

Comment: Nice one. I didn't realize that delimiters can be changed for each successive file

Comment: What is hypen(-)  utilized for in this situation?

Comment: I noticed the `:|` before the `paste`, what is that for?

Comment: @JuanDavila: the hypen tells `paste` to take the "file" from `stdin` instead of from an actual "file"

Comment: @JuanDavila: `:|` is a no-op.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/$/, /' file1 | paste -d '\0' - file2
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
paste -d, file1 file2 > file3
```

output (file3):

```
1,John
2,Sam
3,George
4,Ken
```

Comment: Okay, that seems to legit.  I suppose the hyphen has some meaning in the paste command as well?

Comment: @JuanDavila, it's a common convention for *nix commands to take command-line options that change or specify behavior. `-d` is one such flag. Reading `man paste` will show you exactly what it does.